# Как изменить внешний вид PreferenceFragment в коде программы?

Tags: android, java

Не получается изменить внешний вид PreferenceFragment. Вот, что имеется:

```
public class MenuFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if (v != null) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        lv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100,100));
    }
    return v;
 }
}
```

В данном примере padding изменяется, а LayoutParams выдает ошибку(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams).
Так же не знаю как поменять цвет текста и высоту ячейки.
Благодарю заранее!

---

Стоп! Эту проблему я решил, изменив new LayoutParams(100,100) на new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100). Но, как оказалось, это размеры всего ListView, а не одного пункта. А как изменить размер пункта?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос!